# How to Load only Active Tab Content in Devex PageControl

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using Devex PageControl for Tabs in Asp.net WebForm
as I observed all Tab Content is Loaded in the PageLoad itself
Is it Possible to Load only Active Tab Content On Page Load and 
Load other Tab on Callback.

I am Trying to Reduce the Load Time of the Page

Please Suggest the Solution

Comment: You will have to bypass the default behaviour of the DevExpress control and use something like AJAX to load content of other (inactive) tabs when they become active / focused... Even more user-friendly would be to load the content of the active tab immediate and the other content in the background while the user already reads / uses the page ;) Still need some asynchronous loading mechanism.

Comment: how could i achieve this as i am new to use these controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no way to do what you want. If the page takes too long to load all of its contents, maybe the problem is with the code and DB scripts. Only thing you can do is to optimize those until you reach an acceptable speed for loading the whole page.